# How to use auto-launch to start app on system startup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, electron-builder, electron-packager

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "electronapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "electron auto-launch",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager . --all"
  },
  "author": "ivie",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "Q": "^1.0.0",
    "asar": "^0.13.0",
    "electron": "^1.7.6",
    "electron-packager": "^9.1.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
    "fs-jetpack": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-electron-installer": "^2.1.0",
    "rcedit": "^0.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "auto-launch": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
var electron = require('electron');
var app = electron.app;
var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
var path = require('path');

app.on('ready', ()=>{
    var mainwindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        icon: "favicon.ico",
        frame:true,
        title:'Menuboard',
        fullscreen: false,
        autoHideMenuBar: false
    })
    mainwindow.openDevTools();
    mainwindow.loadURL('https://www.google.com');
    mainwindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainwindow = null;
    });
});
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
    if(process.platform != 'darwin')
        app.quit();
})
```

I have generated an electron .exe using this code. It's getting executed when I'm double clicking on it. But, I want to run it on windows startup. I got to know about auto-launch. But, I'm not sure how to use it in my application? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 27):

Load auto-launch module:

```
const AutoLaunch = require('auto-launch');
```

Then add this after `app.on('ready', ()=>{`:

```
  let autoLaunch = new AutoLaunch({
    name: 'Your app name goes here',
    path: app.getPath('exe'),
  });
  autoLaunch.isEnabled().then((isEnabled) => {
    if (!isEnabled) autoLaunch.enable();
  });
```

Comment: Does this starts the app automatically post installations as well?

Comment: Will it work even if user is not logged in?

Answer (score 22):

FYI this is now provided by Electron out of the box:

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetloginitemsettingssettings-macos-windows

Example:

```
const electron = require("electron")

electron.app.setLoginItemSettings({
    openAtLogin: arg.settings.startOnStartup,
    path: electron.app.getPath("exe")
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on new comments, this may be out of date. Consider trying Timur Nugmanov's answer first.

Comment: Does this work on all platforms, or does it need to be modified at all or linux and mac?

Comment: I only used windows for my app so I couldn't tell you.

Comment: This did not work for me, because it was complaining about the args. The answer provided just bellow this answer worked fine.

Comment: This works fine for me on macOS (Electron 11.2.3)

Comment: +1 that it works fine for both Mac and Windows. I ran into some issues getting it to work on Windows initially because I didn't set the Application User Model ID and it ran into some conflicts in the registry `app.setAppUserModelId`. If you run into issues with windows, you can debug it by looking into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry.

Answer (score 12):

At current electron release(19.0.0), the code below works fine:

```
app.setLoginItemSettings({
    openAtLogin: true    
})
```

Comment: Easiest solution as of March 2023.

Comment: According to the docs, this only works on Windows and Mac...