# electron tray and auto start function doesnt work after building .exe

Tags: node.js, electron

I had build an electron app with the tutorial from [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/262/how-to-build-publish-a-release-distribution-of-an-electron-application-with-the-cli).

The problem is now, that the "minimize to tray" function and the 'autostart' function doesnt work anymore. When starting my app via `npm start` it works but not with the .exe

The code of the tray function is from this answer: [Electron.js How to minimize/close window to system tray and restore window back from tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980563/10122822)

The code of the autostart function is from here: [How to use auto-launch to start app on system startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502817/10122822)

Does anybody know why those functions doesnt work anymore after building a .exe? (Start as admin doesnt help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this doesn't work for was that the path of the icon of the tray menu was defined as `./icon.png` but after building the application, the file isn't at the same place anymore. All the app files are moved to `./resources/app/`.

So this was the fix for me:

```
let trayIcon = null
if(!app.isPackaged) {
  trayIcon = './icon.png'; // when in dev mode
} else {
  trayIcon = './resources/app/icon.png';
}
```